# Many to many relation SQLAlchemy (does relation exsist attribute)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm re-asking this question but with a different framework this time. I have two Models: User and Book with a M2M-relation. I want Book to have an attribute "read" that is True when the relation exists. Is this possible in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Expressions as Mapped Attributes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html?highlight=column_property#sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes). Something like this should do the job for you:

```
Book.read = column_property(
        select(
            [func.count(user_to_book_table.c.user_id)],
            user_to_book_table.c.book_id == book_table.c.id
        ).label('read')
    )
```

Even though it is not Boolean, you can still use it in the IF statements correctly:

```
if mybook.read:
    print 'very popular book indeed'
```

Alternatively you can just add a computed (read-only) property on the Book object, but this will load all the Users into your session:

```
@property
def read(self):
    return len(self.books)!=0
```